# Change color of active terminal in terminator

Tags: terminator

I am using terminator and split it in multiple terminals. I want the terminal's background or text color to change when I switch between terminals.
I am using ubuntu14.04.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you mean different terminal windows or different sections of a split window? You want the colour to change to something random every time it receives focus?

Comment: When split terminator screen to new one. Then when we move focus to new one bicolor should be change. Normally I split terminator to multiple console. For quick activity I would like to change color when I am on that console.

Comment: That's a start, but you didn't say what colors. Do you want the active one to be one color and the inactive another or something else?

Comment: Yes, active one should be of different color any color, others will remain same.